# how to delete a node in <p: tree of primefaces?

Tags: java, primefaces

I am using `private TreeNode root;` to create a dynamycal tree.

and I used

```
<p:tree value="#{bean.root}" var="node">
    <p:treeNode>
        h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

to display it in my page.

my question is how to remove the nodes that are empty (doesn't contain a child)

exemple :

```
node1
   child 1
   child 2
node2 
node3
  child 1
```

(node 2 is empty, how to remove it?)

Answer (score 7):

You can first get all the childs looping the tree:

```
List<TreeNode> nodes = this.root.getChildren();
```

Then you can maybe do something like this:

```
List<TreeNode> nodes = ....
Iterator<TreeNode> i = nodes.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   TreeNode = i.next(); 
   // Use isLeaf() method to check doesn't have childs.
   i.remove();
}
```

It would be the correct version of the next code because I guess you can't remove collection elements in a loop.

```
for (TreeNode treeNode : nodes) {
   if(treeNode.isLeaf()){
       TreeNode parent = treeNode.getParent();
       parent.getChildren().remove(treeNode);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: There isn't a remove() method on TreeNode, neither in DefaultTreeNode. https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.0/org/primefaces/model/TreeNode.html

Comment: Take into account that the `remove()` is used for the `getChildren` which is a `List`, not a `TreeNode`. Is the `remove()` method of the `List` data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
dropNode.getParent().getChildren().removeIf(n -> n==dropNode);
```